# Replace a URI parameter (artical id) with alias value (artical title) in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo, codeigniter-url

I have the following URL in Code Igniter:

> http://example.com/Mysite/News/id

where:

- News: the controller name
- id: a parameter used to retrieve the corresponding news from DB

This would render a news with this id (also with title and body, etc.)
I need to display (and only display) the url as this alias.

> http://example.com/Mysite/News/news-title

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP is_numeric function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

> is_numeric — Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string

```
public function news($parameter)
{
    $this->load->database();

    // If the parameter is number, fetch data with id.
    if ( is_numeric($parameter) ){        
        $news = $this->db->from('news')
                         ->where('id', $id)
                         ->get()->row_array();
    }
    // Otherwise, fetch data with title
    else{
        $news = $this->db->from('news')
                         ->where('title', $title)
                         ->get()->row_array();
    }

    // Render them
}
```